# "automatically manage signing" in xcode is revoking certificates

Tags: xcode

my client has two distribution certificates created for 2 different teams one expiring on feb 7,2018 and another on feb 27, 2018. I am working on an apple watch app. as the bundle identifiers are appended with "watchkitextension", I am not able to manually set the code signing authority. I have to set it to "automatically manage signing". now when i am trying to upload the build to testflight, xcode is warning me that distribution profile is not downloaded and asking me to reset. where as I have the certificate which is expiring on Feb 7, 2018 in my keychain. This is the certificate which i want. But in turn, upon reseting, Xcode is going ahead and revoking the other certificate.
How can i handle this situation? My provision profile is mapped to feb 7, 2018 certificate.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.